# Pandas find specific string from row index and return value to new column

Tags: pandas, pivot-table

I'm creating a new column based on if a student ever re-tested a subject based on the 'file' column:

This is the row data:

[image]

This is how I want to achieve:

[image]

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['file', 'class', 'student', 'subject', 'scores'],
              data=[['re_test', 'A', 'John', 'Math', 60], 
                    ['first_test', 'A', 'Scott', 'Math', 75], 
                    ['first_test', 'A', 'Mary', 'Math', 80],
                    ['re_test', 'B', 'Jack', 'Math', 70], 
                    ['first_test', 'B', 'Mina', 'Math', 75],
                    ['first_test', 'B', 'James', 'Math', 95]])
 
df_math= df.pivot_table(index= ['class', 'student', 'file'],
           values=['subject'], aggfunc=['count'], fill_value = 0)

def retest_check(res):
    res_check = []

    if 're' in res['file']:
        res_check.append(f'Yes')
    else:
        res_check.append(f'No')

    return res_check

df_math['Re-test'] = df_math.apply(retest_check, axis=1)
```

My code gives me an error that it seems cannot identify the string in 'file' column. How can I solve this problem?

> KeyError: 'file'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this approach:

```
(df.query('subject == "Math"')
   .groupby(['class', 'student'])
   .agg({'subject': 'count',
         'file': lambda s: 'Yes' if 're_test' in s.values else 'No',
        })
   .rename(columns={'subject': 'Math (Count)', 'file': 'Re-test'})
)
```

output:

```
               Math (Count) Re-test
class student                      
A     John                1     Yes
      Mary                1      No
      Scott               1      No
B     Jack                1     Yes
      James               1      No
      Mina                1      No
```

Comment: Thank you so much mozway! This is almost what I want. My another requirement is to search a specific string 're' in the 'file' column. Is there a way to modify the lambda function? My real dataset in 'file' column is longer and complex than just a string of 're-test'. For example, 'Univesity-Class123-Math-re_test-20210804_201414". I can only identify by substring 're' as the indicator to point out retest or not.

Comment: Sure, you can replace `'re_test' in s.values` with `s.str.match('.*re_').sum()>0`. (Here I tested for "re_", not "re" as you have less likely the chance to get a match with a common word (e.g., University-O**re**gon would match with just **re**)

Comment: Hi mozway, pardon for another question. If I need to return "Yes" with the timestamp using the example 'Univesity-Class123-Math-re_test-20210804_201414' to the Re-test column. How can I achieve this? I tried `lambda s: 'Yes, {}'.format(s.str.extract(r'(\d{8})')` but it seems return every row of dataset.